# Multiple Javascript Clocks

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I followed a tutorial for building a JS analogue clock and now I'd like to create an identical second clock on the page to experiment with.

When I've tried adding a second clock it overwrites the first clock - I believe this is because the variables `ctx` and `radius` are set globally.

Working example:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("cambs_clock");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
ctx.translate(radius, radius);
radius = radius * 0.90;

//drawClock();
setInterval(drawClock, 1000);

function drawClock() 
{
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}
```

I tried turning the block of code that generates the `ctx` and `radius` variables into a function and adding params to the `drawClock` function but that resulted in no clocks being drawn whatsoever:

```
function setupClock(clock)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cambs_clock");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.90;
    setInterval(drawClock(ctx, radius), 1000);
}

//drawClock();
//setInterval(drawClock, 1000);
setupClock();

function drawClock(ctx,radius) 
{
  drawFace(ctx, radius);
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
  drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius) {
  var grad;

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'red';
  ctx.fill();

  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0, 0 ,radius * 0.95, 0, 0, radius * 1.05);
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'black');
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.05;
  ctx.stroke();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius * 0.1, 0, 2 * Math.PI);
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius) {
  var ang;
  var num;
  ctx.font = radius * 0.15 + "px arial";
  ctx.textBaseline = "middle";
  ctx.textAlign = "center";
  for(num = 1; num < 13; num++){
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, -radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
    ctx.rotate(ang);
    ctx.translate(0, radius * 0.85);
    ctx.rotate(-ang);
  }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
  var now = new Date();
  var hour = now.getHours();
  var minute = now.getMinutes();
  var second = now.getSeconds();
  //hour
  hour = hour%12;
  hour = (hour*Math.PI/6)+(minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+(second*Math.PI/(360*60));
  drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);
  //minute
  minute = (minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
  drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);
  // second
  second = (second*Math.PI/30);
  drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth = width;
  ctx.lineCap = "round";
  ctx.moveTo(0,0);
  ctx.rotate(pos);
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length);
  ctx.stroke();
  ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>
```

The above code results in no clocks being drawn.
How would I be able to expand this code to accommodate multiple clocks?

(The end game is to have several clocks for different timezones in case that makes a difference)

Comment: The crucial line is this: `var canvas = document.getElementById("cambs_clock");` Make `"cambs_clock"` into a variable, create multiple `<canvas>` elements each with its own `id`, then pass the id to the setup function.

Comment: And you will have to adjust the `setInterval()` call because `setInterval(drawClock(ctx, radius), 1000)` does not what you might think it does.

Comment: Thanks andreas that was exactly the issue as user super pointed out in another reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 setInterval(drawClock(ctx, radius), 1000);
```

to

```
  setInterval(() => {
       drawClock(ctx, radius);
  }, 1000);
```

Answer (score 2):

You have tried the following:

```
function setupClock(clock)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById("cambs_clock");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.90;
    setInterval(() => drawClock(ctx, radius), 1000);
}

setupClock();
```

Notice that that function has an argument, `clock` which is not used. Furthermore, with `document.getElementById("cambs_clock");` you always target the same canvas. So what you need in your case are two canvas's like

```
<canvas id="clock1"></canvas>
<canvas id="clock2"></canvas>
```

And the following script

```
function setupClock(clock)
{
    var canvas = document.getElementById(clock);
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var radius = canvas.height / 2;
    ctx.translate(radius, radius);
    radius = radius * 0.90;
    setInterval(drawClock(ctx, radius), 1000);
}

setupClock('clock1');
setupClock('clock2');
```

You can pass the radius as well as an argument if you like:

```
function setupClock(clock, radius) { ... }

setupClock('clock2', 20);
```

Endless possibilities, good luck!

Comment: Whoops I forgot I had hard-coded `cambs_clock` during testing.
Unfortunately even changing that still didn't work as the `setInterval` command was setup incorrectly as @super pointed out in another reply.
Thanks for your help!